# Gravity is going up instead of down?

Tags: python, pygame

Tried making gravity that would make the character go down, instead the character is going up and I have no idea why. My code - `

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import QUIT

background_colour = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
(width, height) = (800, 400)

window = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
background = pygame.Surface(window.get_size())
ts, w, h, c1, c2 = 50, *background.get_size(), (128, 128, 128), (64, 64, 64)
tiles = [((x*ts, y*ts, ts, ts), c1 if (x+y) % 2 == 0 else c2) for x in range((w+ts-1)//ts) for y in range((h+ts-1)//ts)]
[pygame.draw.rect(background, color, rect) for rect, color in tiles]

rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 20, 20)
rect.center = window.get_rect().center
speed = 3.4
speed2 = 5
```

The gravity is implemented here and I cannot find out why the gravity is going up instead of down like it should.

```
#main application loop

run = True
while run:
    gravity = -2
    # limit frames per second
    clock.tick(100)
    # event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    # update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input 
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    rect.x += (keys[pygame.K_d] - keys[pygame.K_a]) * speed
    rect.y += (keys[pygame.K_s] - keys[pygame.K_w]) * speed2
    rect.y = rect.y + gravity
    border_rect = window.get_rect()
    rect.clamp_ip(border_rect)

    # clear the display and draw background
    window.blit(background, (0, 0))

    # draw the scene   
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), rect)

    # update the display
    pygame.display.flip()


dt = 0
x = 30
y = 30
w = 30
h = 30
a = 30
e = 30
l = 30
k = 30


def draw():
    square = pygame.draw.rect(window, RED, pygame.Rect(30, 30, 60, 60), 2)
    pygame.display.flip()


def screen_bound():
    global x
    global y
    global w
    global h
    global a
    global e
    global l
    global k
    # hit right wall
    if ((x+w) > width):
        x = width - w
    # hit floor
    if ((y+h) > height):
        y = height - h
    # hit left wall
    if (x < 0):
        x = 0
    # hit roof
    if (y < 0):
        y = 0


def handle_events():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                pass


def start():
    draw()
    screen_bound()
    handle_events()

    
pygame.quit()
exit()`
```

I've tried to google and find out the problem, but I am new to coding and can't understand much of what people are saying.

Answer (score 2):

The upper left coordinate of the Pygame coordinate system is (0, 0) and the lower right coordinate is (width, height). Therefore, if you want to move an object down, you have to increase the y-coordinate of the object, but not decrease it (`gravity = 2` instead of `gravity = -2`):

```py
gravity = 2

run = True
while run:
    # [...]

    rect.y += gravity 

    # [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Pygame Top left corner is (0,0) and **Y level keeps going down as you increase number** (positive number not negative)

So change the code

```
gravity = -2
```

to as

```
gravity = 2
```

I hope it fixes your problem

(This Answer is Edited )

Comment: I think you mean `gravity = 2`, the plus is implicit. `+=2` will cause an error as `gravity` hasn't been defined.

Comment: ofc thk for saying let me edit it